# Showing only days in React Datepicker calendar

Tags: react-datepicker

I am trying to use React Datepicker in my React application. I am following this document - https://reactdatepicker.com/

I need a date picker which will only show 31 days.

Here is the simple code from the react-datepicker documents.

<DatePicker selected={dayPicker}            onChange={(date) =>                             setDayPicker(date)}                                dateFormat="yyy/MM/dd"                     isClearable={true}

/>

It shows the full calendar. How can I customize the calendar ? Is it possible to remove the header from the calendar and replace it with a text "Days" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will give you date picker for current year with only Month in header.
You just need to use `renderCustomHeader` property of DatePicker.

```
    const year = 2022; // can be provided externally
    const month = 2; // can be provided externally
    const date = 24; // can be provided externally
    
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date(year, month, date));
    const minDate = new Date(year, month, 1);
    const maxDate = new Date(year, month + 1 , 0);
    
    const renderDayContents = (day, date) => {
    if(date < minDate || date > maxDate){
      return <span></span>;
    }
    return <span>{date.getDate()}</span>;
  };
    
    return ( 
        <DatePicker
        selected = {startDate}
        minDate = {minDate}
        maxDate = {maxDate}
        onChange = {(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        renderCustomHeader = {() => <div></div>}
        renderDayContents = {renderDayContents}
        dateFormat = "dd"
        />
    );
```

This is how it will look:

[image]

Explaination:

1. We can create out customer header with the `renderCustomHeader` property of DatePicker.
2. This functions returns JSX (kind of html) which has empty div as we don't want to show anything in header.
3. Apart from `renderCustomHeader` property, we have set `minDate` and `maxDate` property of DatePicker to restrict it for current month.
4. You need to copy above code in a component where you are using DatePicker.

You can refer https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-custom-header to know more about custom header for DatePicker

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243309/discussion-on-answer-by-shreekesh-murkar-showing-only-days-in-react-datepicker-c).

Comment: You have kept year, month and day fixed.how to make them dynamic ?

Comment: You need to pass those values as props in the main component where you are using DatePicker

Comment: You might as well go through https://dev.to/turpp/passing-data-between-react-components-af7

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how to link year , month and day ? Like selecting February should render 28 days in the day input.

Comment: I advice you to learn it by yourself. you will understand it. Stack Over Flow it a platform to get answer if you stuck somewhere. But first you need to try it yourself. If your main question got answered then you need to except the answer and to resolved the question. Have a great day ! Keep learning !!!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But there is an error in your code.you didn't define getDate in <span>{getDate(date)}</span>

Comment: Modified a code bit. instead of getDate(date) use date.getDate(). You need to import one package for getDate to work but as of now you can use  date.getDate().

Comment: You can refer this repository of DatePicker https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/tree/baa41ec15a05668224ec6c9e5678b0ca80200bfb